# Issues with touch buttons in XNA (Release state to be precise)

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, touch, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make touch buttons in WP8 with all the states (Pressed, Released, Moved), but the `TouchLocationState.Released` is not working.

Here's my code:

Class variables:

```
bool touching = false;
int touchID;
Button tempButton;
```

*Button is a separate class with a method to switch states when touched.*

The Update method contains the following code:

```
TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();

if (!touching && touchCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            touching = true;

            foreach (TouchLocation location in touchCollection)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < menuButtons.Count; i++)
                {
                    touchID = location.Id; // store the ID of current touch
                    Point touchLocation = new Point((int)location.Position.X, (int)location.Position.Y); // create a point
                    Button button = menuButtons[i]; 

                    if (GetMenuEntryHitBounds(button).Contains(touchLocation)) // a method which returns a rectangle.
                    {
                        button.SwitchState(true); // change the button state
                        tempButton = button; // store the pressed button for accessing later
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (touchCollection.Count == 0) // clears the state of all buttons if no touch is detected
        {
            touching = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < menuButtons.Count; i++)
            {
                Button button = menuButtons[i];
                button.SwitchState(false);
            }
        }
```

*menuButtons is a list of buttons on the menu.*

A separate loop (within the Update method) after the touched variable is true

```
if (touching)
{
    TouchLocation location;
    TouchLocation prevLocation;

    if (touchCollection.FindById(touchID, out location))
    {
          if (location.TryGetPreviousLocation(out prevLocation))
          {
                Point point = new Point((int)location.Position.X, (int)location.Position.Y);

                if (prevLocation.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed && location.State == TouchLocationState.Released)
                {
                       if (GetMenuEntryHitBounds(tempButton).Contains(point))
                              // Execute the button action. I removed the excess 
                }
           }
     }
}
```

The code for switching the button state is working fine but the code where I want to trigger the action is not.

`location.State == TouchLocationState.Released` mostly ends up being false.
(Even after I release the touch, it has a value of `TouchLocationState.Moved`)
And what is more irritating is that it sometimes works!

I am really confused and stuck for days now. Is this the right way? If yes then where am I going wrong? Or is there some other more effective way to do this?

*PS: I also posted this question on stack overflow then realized this question is more appropriate in gamedev. Sorry if it counts as being redundant.*

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution myself. It does not need the `released` state of the `TouchLocationState`

Posting it here. Hopefully it'll help others.
Thanks if anyone was trying.

The class variables are renamed:

```
private Point _touchPoint;
private TouchLocation _touchLocation;
private int _touchID;
private Button _selectedButton;
private bool _touched;
private bool _launchEvent;
```

The update method now has the following code

```
        TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();

        if (!_touched && touchCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            _touched = false;
            _launchEvent = false;

            foreach (TouchLocation location in touchCollection)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < menuButtons.Count; i++)
                {
                    Button button = menuButtons[i];
                    _touchID = location.Id;
                    _touchPoint = new Point((int)location.Position.X, (int)location.Position.Y);

                    if (GetButtonHitBounds(button).Contains(_touchPoint))
                    {
                        button.SwitchState(true);
                        _selectedButton = button;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (touchCollection.Count == 0)
        {
            _touched = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < menuButtons.Count; i++)
            {
                Button button = menuButtons[i];
                button.SwitchState(false);

                if (GetButtonHitBounds(button).Contains(_touchPoint) && _launchEvent)
                {
                    OnReleased(i, PlayerIndex.One);
                    _launchEvent = false;
                }
            }
        }

        ///
        // This if statement checks whether the touch is still inside the button area.
        // Then assigns a value of true to the _launchEvent variable.
        //
        // The 'try' block is used because if the first touch is not on button, then the
        // value of the _selectedButton is null and it will throw an exception.
        ///
        if (touchCollection.FindById(_touchID, out _touchLocation))
        {
            if (_touchLocation.State == TouchLocationState.Moved)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (GetButtonHitBounds(_selectedButton).Contains((int)_touchLocation.Position.X, (int)_touchLocation.Position.Y))
                        _launchEvent = true;
                    else
                        _launchEvent = false;
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You posted a lot of code. What exactly did you change to fix this? You should at least describe that in your answer.

Comment: You should also check if `_selectedButton == null` instead of try/catch (which can have horrible performance implications), and you should put if bracket statements in curly braces `if (condition) { ... } else { ... }`